# JavaScript Create function

Tags: javascript, html

How can i define following object properties of html and define as a function in `javascript` that would return some object.

HTML:

```
<object id="desktop" type="application/x-desktop" width="500" height="200">
<param name="client_type" value="VISTA" /> </object>
```

I want to acheive something like below in javascript.So that I can call GetDesktop() function from outside of javascript.

JavaScript:

```
 function GetDesktop()
  {
    object.id = "desktop;
    object.type = "application/x-desktop"
     ....
     ...
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new HTML element, or return information about one that is already on the page?

Answer (score 2):

You want to return the HTML above from a JS function?

```
var GetDesktop = function(){
    var obj = document.createElement('object');
    obj.setAttribute('id', 'desktop');
    obj.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-desktop');
    obj.setAttribute('width', '500');
    obj.setAttribute('height', '200');
    var param = document.createElement('param');
    param.setAttribute('name', 'client_type');
    param.setAttribute('value', 'VISTA');
    obj.appendChild(param);

    return obj;
}
```

Obviously if any of those properties need to change, you can pass them in as parameters to the function...

Comment: Strictly speaking, those `setAttribute()` calls are unnecessary.  `obj.id = 'desktop';` will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks tkone. That's exactly what I was looking for.Parameters will be always fixed.

Comment: @aroth They are but this way the op could easily loop through a hash of key/val pairs to set them.

Comment: @user1029083 if this solution worked for you you should click the accept button showing that it satisfied your question.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the question is the opposite of @tkone's.  Hopefully one of us is right. :)

Is this browser Javascript?  If so, then why not use the HTMLElement object directly?

```
var obj = document.getElementById('desktop');
```

That gets you an object for which this is true:

```
obj.getAttribute('id') // -> 'desktop'
obj.getAttribute('type') //-> 'application/x-desktop'
```

*etc.*

If you want a simple JS object with attributes that are stored directly, you can create one by looping through the DOM attributes:

```
   var elem = document.getElementById('desktop');
   var obj = {};
   var attrCount = elem.attributes.length;
   for (var i=0; i<attrCount; ++i) {
      var attr = elem.attributes[i];
      obj[attr.name] = attr.value
   }
```

That gets you an object for which this is true:

```
obj.id // -> 'desktop'
obj.type //-> 'application/x-desktop'
```

*etc*.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes this is browser java script.I am writing Javascript SDK API. So I want to define this in Javascript itself.